# Ansible Playbooks do not run when PowerShell\7\ Environment Path Variable comes before PowerShell\v1.0\

Tags: powershell, ansible, environment-variables, ansible-2.x

I am running a playbook that installs PowerShell 7 onto a Windows VM.

Inside this playbook, I need to switch the order of `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\` and `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\` , so the former comes first in Env:Path, which I successfully do. (This step has to happen for other programs and processes we conduct)

The problem now is that playbooks do not run at all, and I get this error

```
FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm send_input failed; \nstdout: 
\nstderr 'PowerShell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
}
```

I believe the issue is that Ansible tries to reference PowerShell 7, which does not work (for some reason, please let me know why if you can). Is there a way for Ansible to always reference `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the win_path module did exactly what I wanted to achieve and actually does it correctly. Solved all my problems